# mongo java 3.0 driver remove all

Tags: mongodb-java

I don't want to drop the collection and recreate it, though if that is the recommended way, I guess I'll do that.
It used to be there was a `collection.removeAll()` method...

there is a `collection.deleteMany( bson )` , but is there a "match-all" Filter available? (my first pass through I couldn't find anything).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the closest you will find is:

```
collection.deleteMany(new Document());
```

That's effectively equivalent to `db.collection.remove({})` in the Mongo shell.